# How to divide a file into multiple diffs in git

Tags: git, github

I have a file sequencer.cpp that has been modified but I need to create two diffs each for a different function.
How do I make two unique and different diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean that you'd like to commit the two functions individually. This is done by staging one hunk (or piece of the file) which is your first function to commit, then committing, then staging the other hunk (i.e. your other function) then committing.

- Make sure your `sequencer.cpp` file is not staged with `git reset HEAD sequencer.cpp`
- Start an interactive add  `git add -i` (the git command for more fine grained add commands)
- `p` for "Patch"
- [Stage the patches of the first function to commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging#Staging-Patches)
- Commit
- Repeat the process but instead stage the hunks of the other function